# If $j\mid (a-b)$ and $j\mid (b-c)$ then $j\mid (a-c)$ . Why is this true?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, definition

Why is this true?

> If $j\mid (a-b)$ and $j\mid (b-c)$ then $j\mid (a-c)$ .

Assuming all the variables stated are any integers.

Is it true because we use the $a\mid b$ is $ka=b$ definition?

Comment: $(a-c)=(a-b+b-c)=(a-b)+(b-c)$.

Comment: $j|(a-b)$ is $j \times k_1=(a-b)$ and $j|(b-c)$ is $j \times k_2=(b-c)$.

Comment: Thus $j \times (k_1+k_2)=(a-b)+(b-c)=(a-c)$.

Comment: "Is it true because we use the $a\mid b$ is $ka=b$ definition?" **Yes**. Next question?

Comment: Please use the body of the Question to give a full statement on the problem you want help with.  It's fine to put the problem statement basics in the title, but the extra space allowed by the body helps you to give a complete phrasing to help Readers understand your concerns (and respond appropriately).

Answer (score 2):

$$j\mid b-c \implies b-c=k_1j ,k_1 \in \mathbb{Z}\\
j\mid a-b \implies a-b=k_2j ,k_2 \in \mathbb{Z}\\$$so  by summation we have 
$$b-c=k_1j\\
a-b=k_2j \\a-c=(k_1+k_2)j \implies j\mid a-c \\\text{or} \\j\mid c-a$$

Comment: @Arthur:thank you for notification , sorry , I made it right